# How can I show dotted gridLines with ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

[image]
I am developing a chart in chart.js and I want to show dotted gridlines like shown in the image.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can edit your dataset display in your chart options :

```js
options: {
    scales: {
        // The following will affect the vertical lines (xAxe) of your dataset
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                // You can change the color, the dash effect, the main axe color, etc.
                borderDash: [8, 4],
                color: "#348632"
            }
        }],

        // And this will affect the horizontal lines (yAxe) of your dataset
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                borderDash: [8, 4],
                color: "#348632"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Now that you know how to do it, just change it as how you want it to be.
Check [Grid Line Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration) on Chart.js documentation to see what is editable.

If needed, here are a working example [on this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4bvnupj/) and its result :

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Link is broken for "Grid Line Configuration" and above code seems to not make the chart look like the OPS question due to grid lines in the background. using a "destination-over" to make the grid lines on top breaks tooltips and bubble points.

Comment: I didn't see the doc mentioned how to limit the gridline below the chart line...the answer doesn't mention it either.

Answer (score 13):

I am working with chart.js version: 9.2.0.For me worked the following code:

```
options: {
    cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone',
    plugins: {legend: false},
    scales: {
        x: {
            grid:{
                color: 'magenta',
            },
            border: {
                dash: [2,4],
            },  
            ticks: {display: false}
        },
        y: {
            grid: {
                color: 'magenta',
            },
            border: {
                dash: [2,4],
            }, 
            ticks: {
                callback: function(value) {
                    return value + 'k';
                }
            }
       }
    }
}
```

The result I got:
[the result, the chart with dashed grid lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDf9Z.png)

The main part is `border: {dash: [2,4]}`. I found it experimentally, as solutions with  `gridLines: {borderDash: [8, 4]}` didt work for me, so it could be not the best solution

I found the information at [chart.js page about axes styling](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#border-configuration)

Comment: Thank you, i was adding the border property to grid instead of y

Comment: @Cuado Same here xD